# Styling order of Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've spent like 10 hours on customization to understand it perfectly but it makes me headache as I go on.

I'm styling outlined `TextField`, specifically its label and border.
I thought it wouldn't be problematic if I use `sx` prop to customize but it didn't work well as I had expected.

```js
const One = () => (
  <div>
    <TextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="One"
      variant="outlined"
      sx={{
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
          borderRadius: 0
        },

        "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
          color: "orange"
        },

        "& .Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "orange"
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

**I want label to be orange always, and border to be orange when focused**. But when I focus on the `TextField`, label and border go back to blue. But border-radius works well.

I inspected the result and it seemed like **default style was inserted again when the component was focused. I don't get it because I think it should have been inserted earlier, like when the `TextField` mounted.** Why is `sx` prop not overriding the default style?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-customization-zg5v5v?file=/src/components/One.jsx

Comment: did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the specificity of the focused class selector by adding it to the root.

```
const One = () => (
  <div>
    <TextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="One"
      variant="outlined"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          borderRadius: 0,
        },

        '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
          color: 'orange',
        },

        '&  .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: 'orange',
        },
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

This oughta do it for ya!

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your last style in your first style

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="One"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      borderRadius: 0,
      "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: "orange",
        color: "inherit"
      }
    },

    "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
      color: "orange"
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working code that keeps the label always orange.

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="One"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "black" // or your default/initial color
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "orange"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "orange"
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
      color: "orange", // This is how you add the color to the label
      "&.Mui-focused": {
        color: "orange" // This is how you add the color to the label on focus
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Here is your working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-customization-forked-5vk8yo?file=/src/components/One.jsx:130-770) edited